# Can I pass cursor?

Tags: oracle, procedure

I get cursor as output from `method1` and I want to pass the cursor to `method2` as input parameter. But this cursor becomes `null` once I pass this cursor to `method2`.

Does anybody have any idea?

```
variable r refcursor;
package_method1(:r);
package_method2(:r);
print r;
```

Comment: Variables do not become null when passed as a parameters. They become null because a program executed a line of code which changes their state. It's not obvious what you're trying to do here, so you need to **edit you question**. Please some internal code for  `package_method1()` and `package_method2()` which reproduces the behaviour. If you can reduce it to a few simple lines of code you're more likely to get helpful answers. You may also get an insight into the code which will allow you to solve it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`:r` is a bind variable and `r` is a variable in the PL/SQL scope; they are different variables.

You probably want:

```
variable r refcursor;
package_method1(:r);
package_method2(:r);
```